# NTLMv1 authentication fails over LDAP (SASL/GSS-SPNEGO)

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ntlm

I have a deployment which boils down to the following -

Client   <======>  |  Web Server   | <=======> |  Win2k3 Server  |

Curl Loader                               [WS]                                      [AD]

The user on the Curl loader (IE 8.0) tries to access pages on WS and is granted access only after the user authenticates to the AD over LDAP The message sequence followed here is quite similar to Section 4.1 in [MS-NTHT] - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc237488%28v=prot.10%29.aspx

When 2 concurrent SASL Bind Request reaches to AD server, then LDAP server ends up rejecting one request stating invalid credentials. The other request authenticates successfully.

Both the client request have identical credentials but the AD always returns "invalidCredentials" despite the username/password being correct(verified multiple times).

Below is the BIND response which i receive from AD.
[AD] => [WS] ::Bind response (invalidCredentials); 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C09043E, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 0, vece

Any pointers on how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think i was able to root cause the issue. Problem was that the challenge which LDAP server was issuing in Type-2 message was not matching with the Challenge which was sent in Type-3 message. Thus, server was not able to identify the message credentials.

Steps for debugging.
Packet Capture Analysis for complete call flow.

Thanks!